# String conversion in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

In Sql server, I want to convert a string 'EN,ES,FR'to ISNULL('EN','') + ISNULL('FR','') + ISNULL('ES',''). What is the easiest way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use coalesce instead? coalesce(EN,ES,FR) Or are you trying concatenate all these column values together?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
declare @list nvarchar(20)
set @list = 'EN,FR,ES'
print 'ISNULL(''' + replace(@list, ',', ''','''') + ISNULL(''') + ''','''')'
```

Output is

```
ISNULL('EN','') + ISNULL('FR','') + ISNULL('ES','')
```

...or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick?!

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks